# Grails - find where date ranges overlap

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a Grails domain object with a startDate and endDate property.

What's the best way to find all those objects where the range [startDate, endDate] overlaps with a specified date range?  I know how to do this in SQL but wonder if there's any Grails/GORM magic to do it more succinctly.

Also, the endDate is an optional property.

The SQL / JPQL query would be something like

```
from MyObject obj where obj.startDate <= ?1 and (obj.endDate is null OR obj.endDate >= ?2)
```

Comment: In gorm you can run your hql queries using executequery. See if this helps http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two Ways to embrace Grails/GORM in this case:

**Lazy:-**

```
def today = new Date()
def query = MyObject.where {
    startDate <= (today - 10) && (endDate == null || endDate >= today + 10)
}
def listOfMyObjects = query.list()
```

**Eager:-**

```
def today = new Date()
def listOfMyObjects = MyObject.findAll {//or find{} if you need the first occurance
    startDate <= (today - 10) && (endDate == null || endDate >= today + 10)
}
```

Comment: The eager was exactly what I was looking for.   Is Grails / GORM smart enough to translate that to a SQL WHERE or is it just going to pull the whole list and do it in memory?

Comment: Yes, Grails/GORM is doing it for you, translating it to an HQL underneath which is exactly you meant as Magic earlier. You already know the trick, you just don't want to use it but Grails makes it more verbose for you. :)

Comment: I would upvote this again if I could.  It is absolutely awesome to use a closure to define a criteria idiomatically, as if it were objects in memory, yet ends up being translated to SQL.